# React Native w/ TypeScript this.setState is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, typescript2.0

I'm currently using React Native 0.39.2 w/ newest TypeScript and when I run my componentDidMount() method and setState I get an error around this.setState is not a function.

I tried binding with 
`this.setState({isLoggedIn: true}).bind(this)`

though since I'm using a boolean as the type it won't let me without giving a type error and even setting to any type still gets same error.

here's my code

First with my interface for State

```
import React, {
 Component
} from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import Firestack from 'react-native-firestack';

const firestack = new Firestack();

interface Props {

}

interface State {
  isLoggedIn?: boolean;
}


export default class MainList extends Component<Props, State> {

   state = {
     isLoggedIn: false,
   };

   constructor(props: any) {

      super(props);
      console.log("Is anyone logged in?: " + this.isLoggedIn);

   }

   isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;

   componentDidMount() {

      if (!this.isLoggedIn) {

          Actions.welcome();

      }

      firestack.auth.listenForAuth(function(evt: any) {
      // evt is the authentication event
      // it contains an `error` key for carrying the
      // error message in case of an error
      // and a `user` key upon successful authentication

        if (!evt.authenticated) {
        // There was an error or there is no user
        //console.error(evt.error);

        this.setState({isLoggedIn: false});
        console.log("The state of isLoggedIn is: " +       this.isLoggedIn);

        } else {
        // evt.user contains the user details
        console.log('User details', evt.user);

        this.setState({isLoggedIn: true});
        console.log("The state of isLoggedIn is: " + this.isLoggedIn);

        }


    }); 

}

render() {

    return (
        <View style={styles.View}>

            <Text style={styles.textLabel}>The main view</Text>

        </View>
     )

   }

 }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({

 View: {
    padding: 20
 },
 textLabel: {
    fontSize: 20,
    marginBottom: 10,
    height: 20
 },
 textInput: {
    height: 20,
    fontSize: 15,
    marginBottom: 20
  }

});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MainList', ()=> MainList);
```

Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: post your whole file. how are you declaring your class?

Comment: looks like there is a great deal you are missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because in the callback function for `listenForAuth`, `this` is no longer referring to the `MainList` object.

Try switching to arrow function expression which solve the `this` binding issue:

```
firestack.auth.listenForAuth((evt: any) => {
  ...
});
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is a good read if you want to know more about arrow function.

Comment: thank you so much :-)

i should of realized this but I forgot to mention I am a little new, but this helped so much especially the help reference at the end!

Comment: You are welcome! There are a few other solutions (e.g. `bind(this)` or `var that = this;`), but I find it a lot more easier using arrow function (which was introduced in ES6).

Comment: would I do the var that = this; outside the class definition if i were to do that i'm gathering?

Comment: You can define `var that = this;` inside `componentDidMount()` function, then you can use `that.setState()` in the callback function.